# R creating functions using monte carlo or similar

Tags: r, function, mean, montecarlo

Create a function that will return values from a random distribution centered around an average, with two standard deviations. One above the average, and a second one below the average. A third parameter indicates how many samples are required.

Calculate the resulting average, and plot a histogram of 100,000 random numbers with an average of 20, a high SD of 6, and a low SD of 1.

Hint: make two distributions, reject the ones above the average in one, and below the average in the other. Then select values from both to get the desired number of resulting random numbers.

This is using R programming. I am trying to learn R and it is difficult one.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which random distribution? Normal, uniform, beta, exponential, ...